# How do I encode a string to bytes in the send method of a socket connection in one line?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.5

In Python 3.5, using sockets, I have:

```
message = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n'
s.send(message.encode())
```

How can I do that in one line?  I ask because I had:

```
s.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
```

but in Python 3.5 bytes are required, not a string, so this gives the error:

```
builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Should I not be using send?

Comment: You could have combined the string literal with the `str.encode()` call too, you know: `s.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n'.encode('ascii'))`.
 Not that you need to, what with `b'...'` byte literals.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had tried s.send('mystring').encode('utf-8') so the encode was in the wrong place.

Comment: Because that tries to call `.encode()` on the *return value* of `s.send()`. Look closely at the parentheses; `message.encode()` is entirely contained *inside* `s.send()`. So is my version with `s.send('....'.encode('utf8'))`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str`, the type of *text*, is not the same as `bytes`, the type of *sequences of eight-bit words*. To concisely convert from one to the other, you could inline the call to `encode` (just as you could with any function call)...

```
s.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n'.encode())
```

.. bearing in mind that it's often a good idea to specify the encoding you want to use...

```
s.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n'.encode('ascii'))
```

... but it's simpler to use a [bytes literal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/). Prefix your string with a `b`:

```
s.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
```

But you know what's even simpler? Letting someone else do HTTP for you. Have you thought about using a server such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), or even [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html), to build your app?

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
s.send(b'your text')
```

Adding `b` in front of a string will convert it to `bytes`.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a `b` or `B` before an opening quote will change a `str` literal to a `bytes` literal:

```
s.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
```

Comment: Is there a difference between `b` and `B`?

Comment: @Holloway: Yes, one usually requires the shift key to type, and the other doesn't.

Comment: @jwodder bUT WHAT IF i HAVE A BROKEN cAPS lOCK KEY?