# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when writing to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5001

    server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.sendto (message, server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print ('Received from server: ' + (data))
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

When I run this code the line `s.sendto (message, server)` causes a `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

How do you fix this kind of problem? I tried searching the internet but can't find a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I encode a string to bytes in the send method of a socket connection in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092256/how-do-i-encode-a-string-to-bytes-in-the-send-method-of-a-socket-connection-in-o)

Comment: @scraaappy that's not a good duplicate target; all the answers suggest prepending `b` to a string, but in this case the string is coming from user input, so prepending isn't possible.  Explicitly encoding is better anyway - prepending `b` won't work if the string contains non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 5):

Sockets read and write bytes, not strings (that's a property of sockets in general, not a python-specific implementaiton choice). That's the reason for the error.

Strings have an `encode()` methods that transforms  them to byte-objects. So, instead of writing `my_text`, write `my_text.encode()` to your socket.

Similarly, when you read for the socket, you get a bytes-like object, on which you can call `input_message.decode()` to convert it into string

Comment: Thank you for your help i did what you said and it solve the problem

Comment: @Firaga: thanks, please accept answer if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the fact you are not encoding the message.
Just change:

```
c.sendto(message, server)
```

to

```
c.sendto(message.encode(), server)
```

in your code.

**Example:**

```
    import  socket
    
    s=socket.socket()
    port=12345
    s.bind(('',port))
    print("Socket bind succesfully")
    s.listen(5)
    // note this point 
    message="This is message send to client "
    
    while True:
        c,addr=s.accept()
        // here is error occured 
        c.send(message)
        c.close()
```

> This is will result in an error message:

```
    c.send(message)
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and in order to fix it, we need to change:

```
c.send(message)
```

to

```
c.send(message.encode())
```