# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while trying to send a http request

Tags: python, serversocket

i'm trying to send an http response to a site inputted by the user, then print the response, the code is as follows:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = input("Enter a web address and press Enter: ")
s.connect((url, 80))
# s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
s.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print(s.recv(1028))
s.close()
```

However, i get the mentioned error. Not really sure why. I tried to also concat the send request but said i cannot have a bytes-like object. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried to encode the text from the link sent by Passerby, however I do not get the html response back, I get a bad request:

```
b'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\nReferrer-Policy: no-referrer\r\nContent-Length: 1555\r\nDate: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 22:48:41 GMT\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">\n  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(/'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encode a string to bytes in the send method of a socket connection in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092256/how-do-i-encode-a-string-to-bytes-in-the-send-method-of-a-socket-connection-in-o)

Comment: Not really, I don't get the response back, the layout of site in html

Comment: You don't send RESPONSES to web sites.  You send REQUESTS, and the site sends a response in return.  You should be sending `s.send( b'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n')`.  Better yet, use the excellent `requests` module that hides all of that and lets you focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to do this with sockets? Why not use `urllib.request`?

```py
import urllib.request

url = input("Enter a web address and press Enter: ")

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Here's me running that to hit `https://www.example.com`:

```
Enter a web address and press Enter: https://www.example.com
b'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />\n    <style type="text/css">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 2em;\n        background-color: #fdfdff;\n        border-radius: 0.5em;\n        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        div {\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            width: auto;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Here's how you could do it with `socket`:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = input("Enter a web address and press Enter: ")
s.connect((url, 80))
request = f"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{url}\r\n\r\n"
s.send(request.encode())
print(s.recv(4096))
s.close()
```

I modified this program: https://www.geeks3d.com/hacklab/20190110/python-3-simple-http-request-with-the-socket-module/

If you need it to keep reading until EOF, use this pattern:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
url = input("Enter a web address and press Enter: ")
s.connect((url, 80))
request = f"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:{url}\r\n\r\n"
s.send(request.encode())

response = ""

while True:
    chunk = s.recv(1024)
    if len(chunk) == 0:
        break
    response += str(chunk)

print(response)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to self teach sockets and networking in python. Trying to do it with any external packages.

Comment: `urllib.request` isn't external, it's core Python just like `socket`. But I'll update with a working `socket` example.

Comment: for reading till end of file, don't we need to decode until end= ' '? Also why are we not explicitly decoding as we are encoding?

Comment: No idea, this just seemed to work for me. I don't use `socket` to make HTTP requests. I use `requests` or `urllib.request`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the user for an URL as a string:

```py
url = input("Enter a web address and press Enter: ")
```

Then you pass that string to `socket.send`:

```py
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
```

But, as the error says, `socket.send` expects a **bytes-like object**. To get that from a string, either call it's `encode` method:

```py
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode("utf-8"))
```

or create a `bytes` object from it and pass that to `socket.send`:

```py
s.send(bytes("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"))
```

or put a `b` in front of the string:

```py
s.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
```